# Regex to extract string from a file path R?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following file path with uuid incapsulated within it's path:

> "~/My_Files/F0/F1/F2/0b27ea5fad61c99d/0b27ea5fad61c99d/2015-04-1-04-25-12-925"

I want to extract it using regular expression.
I know that I can just `unlist(strsplit(string, "/"))` and take the 7th element but it seems to me too slow and not efficient problem solving.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
\w{16}
```

I am keep trying to play with this, please advise.

I want to extract the uuid: `0b27ea5fad61c99d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly hacky but compact and regex-free solution:

```
basename(dirname(x))
#[1] "0b27ea5fad61c99d"
```

Where

```
x <- "~/My_Files/F0/F1/F2/0b27ea5fad61c99d/0b27ea5fad61c99d/2015-04-1-04-25-12-925"
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you conducted some benchmarks regarding timing? I think your own solution performs already quite well, especially with the minor improvement of introducing `fixed = T`. See below timings. Why start a complicated regex search when you already know the exact symbols where to split your string...

**Update with respect to comments:** The vectorized versions shows, that f2 shows not the best but still acceptable performance. But as indicated in the comments, vectorized regex approaches will usually perform better with increasing length of the vector - and of course, they are more flexible if you have less knowledge on the structure of your directory names.

**Update 2:** If anyone is still interested, I have updated the function f2 by using a better way for accessing sub-elements of the lists. This now makes it the fastest approach for the specific example, at least, for a benchmark of 500 items.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(stringi)
string = "~/My_Files/F0/F1/F2/0b27ea5fad61c99d/0b27ea5fad61c99d/2015-04-1-04-25-12-925"
string = rep(string, 500)
f1 = function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "/"), `[[`, 7)
f2 = function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "/", fixed = T), `[[`, 7)
f2b = function(x) sapply(stri_split_fixed(string, "/"), `[[`, 7)
f3 = function(x) stri_extract_first_regex(x, "(?=[a-f0-9]+[a-f])(?=[a-f0-9]+[0-9])([a-f0-9]{16})")
f4 = function(x) sapply(x, function(y) tail(unlist(strsplit(dirname(x), "/")),1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
f5 = function(x) basename(dirname(x))
f6 = function(x) gsub("([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/][0-9a-z]+)/(.*)","\\6",x)
f7 = function(x) sub("^.*/(.*)$", "\\1", dirname(x))
f8 = function(x) sub(".*/(.*)/[^/]+$","\\1",x)
bm = microbenchmark(
  (a = f1(string))
  ,(b = f2(string))
  , (b2 = f2b(string))
  ,(c = f3(string))
  , (d = f4(string))
  , (e = f5(string))
  , (f = f6(string))
  , (g = f7(string))
  , (h = f8(string))
  , times = 25)
bm
# Unit: microseconds
# expr                     min          lq         mean      median          uq         max neval
# (a = f1(string))    1894.017    1947.307    2083.6390    2072.444    2142.709    2896.684    25
# (b = f2(string))     532.520     575.153     605.7698     592.917     630.813     823.451    25
# (b2 = f2b(string))   545.152     569.232     617.1387     606.733     637.129     778.450    25
# (c = f3(string))     855.426     894.112     953.5931     946.614     999.511    1286.890    25
# (d = f4(string)) 2497889.661 2538700.607 2604673.5850 2602081.839 2654385.172 2820226.019    25
# (e = f5(string))    4686.881    4935.573    5087.7735    5155.450    5201.240    5544.674    25
# (f = f6(string))    5991.532    6357.861    6750.8284    6584.054    6886.039    9232.438    25
# (g = f7(string))    4313.840    4462.661    4770.6780    4696.749    4900.046    6442.733    25
# (h = f8(string))    2328.637    2422.193    2620.5163    2606.542    2660.229    3697.239    25
all(all.equal(a, b)
    ,all.equal(a, c)
    ,all.equal(a, d)
    ,all.equal(a, e)
    ,all.equal(a, f)
    ,all.equal(a, g)
    ,all.equal(a, b2)
    ,all.equal(a, h)
)
# TRUE
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the 7th element one could use `tail()` in combination with `dirname()` for a more general solution, for instance like this;
`f1 <- function(x) tail(unlist(strsplit(dirname(x), "/")),1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot Manuel! I was sure from previous experience that regex is faster but thanks for your example. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @RHertel why dirname removes the second uuid instance when splitting?

Comment: @steves Could not get to work your regex with R in the way you use it, have you tested it in R? (maybe I am stuck currently, sorry, if so)

Comment: @RHertel Have included your version in the timing benchmark.

Comment: @ManuelBickel sure I have played with it to make it work. All this regex stuff sometimes can be tricky.

Comment: @steves I am not sure if I understand your question. `dirname()` returns the name of the directory. In your example, `2015-04-1-04-25-12-925` would be the filename, which is dropped by `dirname()`.

Comment: Here's another one: `f5 <- function(x) sub("^.*/(.*)$", "\\1", dirname(x))`

Comment: @RHertel I mean that the last uuid hasn't "/" and when strsplit comes to split on "/" it ignores the last uuid instance. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RHertel please explain your regex. It says start at the beginning of the string, match any character 0 or more times, match /, create a group of any char 0 or more times at the end, and take the first occurrence. Meaning that you are aiming on the /uuid part because you're using dirname?

Comment: @steves R does not know that this is a uuid. The string can be interpreted as if it consisted of a structure of the type `${directory}/${filename}`, where the filename is identified by the absence of a `/` at the end.

Comment: you did not try `sub(".*/(.*)/[^/]+$","\\1",x)`

Comment: Added your version. Please note that your proposal has been made after my last edit (see the time stamps). In such cases I am happy to add additional version and interested in their performance. However, I would kindly ask for a more friendly wording in a sense: "Could you please also test the following version..." instead of a sense like "You forgot this and that..". I will try my best to provide a comprehensive comparison...

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** As per Onyambu's comment adding following solution too now.

```
sub(".*/(.*)/[^/]+$","\\1",val)
```

---

Could you please try following `gsub` function to of base `R` and let me know if this helps you.

```
gsub("([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/][0-9a-z]+)/(.*)","\\6",val)
```

***Explanation:*** Here is a brief explanation of above snippet.

`([^/]*)`: Selecting all from starting to till a `/` and keeping it in first place holder of memory.

`/`: Mentioning `/` then.
Again repeating these above 2 steps till 5 times to select 6th field which is mentioned by `([^/][0-9a-z]+)` then `/(.*)` means taking all rest of the matches in 7th memory place.

`"\\6"`: Now substituting whole value of variable `val` with only 6th memory place which is actually required by OP to get the desired results.

Comment: `sub(".*/(.*)/[^/]+$","\\1",x)`

Comment: @Onyambu, sure sir, I have added this solution too in my EDIT, thanks for letting know, cheers sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You might match a forward slash, then use a positive use 2 positive lookaheads `(?=` to assert that what follows is at least `[a-f]` and at least `[0-9]`. Then capture in a group `([a-f0-9]{16})`

[`/(?=[a-f0-9]+[a-f])(?=[a-f0-9]+[0-9])([a-f0-9]{16})`](https://regex101.com/r/j2o6pD/1)

Answer (score 1):

You may use regular expression:

`(?:[^\/]+\/){5}(\w+)`

- `(?:` Start of non capturing group.

  - `[^\/]+\/` Anything except a forward slash `/`, followed by forward slash `/`.
- `)` Close non capturing group.
- `{5}` Match exactly five occurrences of the preceding pattern.
- `(\w+)` Capturing group. Capture alphanumeric characters greedily.

The substring of interest is contained in the capture group.
You can test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/OQJEP6/2).

Comment: The issue is that when I use it in sub function it doesn't recognize the pattern...

Comment: Are you using `perl=TRUE`? See [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) for more details.

Comment: Sure, Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?:[^\/"